# Material Ui Customized Tree not displaying while putting DB data but working with manual input

Tags: json, reactjs, django-rest-framework, material-ui, treeview

I am using react js as my frontend and Django as backend. I'm getting a data from database in tree structure which i wnat to display in a Material ui Tree view. I do checked a by logging a data it is printing a data but not showing a tree.

react js code

```js
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
import { fade, makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring/web.cjs'; // web.cjs is required for IE 11 support

function MinusSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon fontSize="inherit" style={{ width: 14, height: 14 }} {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0zM17.873 11.023h-11.826q-.375 0-.669.281t-.294.682v0q0 .401.294 .682t.669.281h11.826q.375 0 .669-.281t.294-.682v0q0-.401-.294-.682t-.669-.281z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function PlusSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon fontSize="inherit" style={{ width: 14, height: 14 }} {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0zM17.873 12.977h-4.923v4.896q0 .401-.281.682t-.682.281v0q-.375 0-.669-.281t-.294-.682v-4.896h-4.923q-.401 0-.682-.294t-.281-.669v0q0-.401.281-.682t.682-.281h4.923v-4.896q0-.401.294-.682t.669-.281v0q.401 0 .682.281t.281.682v4.896h4.923q.401 0 .682.281t.281.682v0q0 .375-.281.669t-.682.294z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function CloseSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon className="close" fontSize="inherit" style={{ width: 14, height: 14 }} {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M17.485 17.512q-.281.281-.682.281t-.696-.268l-4.12-4.147-4.12 4.147q-.294.268-.696.268t-.682-.281-.281-.682.294-.669l4.12-4.147-4.12-4.147q-.294-.268-.294-.669t.281-.682.682-.281.696 .268l4.12 4.147 4.12-4.147q.294-.268.696-.268t.682.281 .281.669-.294.682l-4.12 4.147 4.12 4.147q.294.268 .294.669t-.281.682zM22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function TransitionComponent(props) {
  const style = useSpring({
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(20px,0,0)' },
    to: { opacity: props.in ? 1 : 0, transform: `translate3d(${props.in ? 0 : 20}px,0,0)` },
  });

  return (
    <animated.div style={style}>
      <Collapse {...props} />
    </animated.div>
  );
}

TransitionComponent.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Show the component; triggers the enter or exit states
   */
  in: PropTypes.bool,
};

const StyledTreeItem = withStyles((theme) => ({
  iconContainer: {
    '& .close': {
      opacity: 0.3,
    },
  },
  group: {
    marginLeft: 7,
    paddingLeft: 18,
    borderLeft: `1px dashed ${fade(theme.palette.text.primary, 0.4)}`,
  },
}))((props) => <TreeItem {...props} TransitionComponent={TransitionComponent} />);

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 264,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400,
  },
});

export default function CustomizedTreeView(props) {
  const {course} = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data,setData] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    setData(course)
  },[])
  /* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
  const makeTree = data =>{<StyledTreeItem nodeId={data.id} label={data.category_name}/>}
  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultExpanded={['1']}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<MinusSquare />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<PlusSquare />}
      defaultEndIcon={<CloseSquare />}
    >
      {console.log("data",data)}
      {/* {makeTree(course)} */}
      {data.map((item,index)=>{
        {console.log("item",item.category_name)}
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId={item.id} label={item.category_name}>

        </StyledTreeItem>
      })}
      <StyledTreeItem nodeId="1" label="Main">
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="2" label="Hello" />
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="3" label="Subtree with children">
          <StyledTreeItem nodeId="6" label="Hello" />
          <StyledTreeItem nodeId="7" label="Sub-subtree with children">
            <StyledTreeItem nodeId="9" label="Child 1" />
            <StyledTreeItem nodeId="10" label="Child 2" />
            <StyledTreeItem nodeId="11" label="Child 3" />
          </StyledTreeItem>
          <StyledTreeItem nodeId="8" label="Hello" />
        </StyledTreeItem>
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="4" label="World" />
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="5" label="Something something" />
      </StyledTreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

[here is the output where the dynamic tree is not displayed while manual do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ogv7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
import { fade, makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring/web.cjs'; // web.cjs is required for IE 11 support

function MinusSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon fontSize="inherit" style={{ width: 14, height: 14 }} {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0zM17.873 11.023h-11.826q-.375 0-.669.281t-.294.682v0q0 .401.294 .682t.669.281h11.826q.375 0 .669-.281t.294-.682v0q0-.401-.294-.682t-.669-.281z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function PlusSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon fontSize="inherit" style={{ width: 14, height: 14 }} {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0zM17.873 12.977h-4.923v4.896q0 .401-.281.682t-.682.281v0q-.375 0-.669-.281t-.294-.682v-4.896h-4.923q-.401 0-.682-.294t-.281-.669v0q0-.401.281-.682t.682-.281h4.923v-4.896q0-.401.294-.682t.669-.281v0q.401 0 .682.281t.281.682v4.896h4.923q.401 0 .682.281t.281.682v0q0 .375-.281.669t-.682.294z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function CloseSquare(props) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon className="close" fontSize="inherit" style={{ width: 14, height: 14 }} {...props}>
      {/* tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length */}
      <path d="M17.485 17.512q-.281.281-.682.281t-.696-.268l-4.12-4.147-4.12 4.147q-.294.268-.696.268t-.682-.281-.281-.682.294-.669l4.12-4.147-4.12-4.147q-.294-.268-.294-.669t.281-.682.682-.281.696 .268l4.12 4.147 4.12-4.147q.294-.268.696-.268t.682.281 .281.669-.294.682l-4.12 4.147 4.12 4.147q.294.268 .294.669t-.281.682zM22.047 22.074v0 0-20.147 0h-20.12v0 20.147 0h20.12zM22.047 24h-20.12q-.803 0-1.365-.562t-.562-1.365v-20.147q0-.776.562-1.351t1.365-.575h20.147q.776 0 1.351.575t.575 1.351v20.147q0 .803-.575 1.365t-1.378.562v0z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}

function TransitionComponent(props) {
  const style = useSpring({
    from: { opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(20px,0,0)' },
    to: { opacity: props.in ? 1 : 0, transform: `translate3d(${props.in ? 0 : 20}px,0,0)` },
  });

  return (
    <animated.div style={style}>
      <Collapse {...props} />
    </animated.div>
  );
}

TransitionComponent.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Show the component; triggers the enter or exit states
   */
  in: PropTypes.bool,
};

const StyledTreeItem = withStyles((theme) => ({
  iconContainer: {
    '& .close': {
      opacity: 0.3,
    },
  },
  group: {
    marginLeft: 7,
    paddingLeft: 18,
    borderLeft: `1px dashed ${fade(theme.palette.text.primary, 0.4)}`,
  },
}))((props) => <TreeItem {...props} TransitionComponent={TransitionComponent} />);

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 264,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400,
  },
});

export default function CustomizedTreeView(props) {
  const {course} = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data,setData] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    setData(course)
  },[])
  /* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */
  const makeTree = data =>{<StyledTreeItem nodeId={data.id} label={data.category_name}/>}
  return (
    <TreeView
      className={classes.root}
      defaultExpanded={['1']}
      defaultCollapseIcon={<MinusSquare />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<PlusSquare />}
      defaultEndIcon={<CloseSquare />}
    >
      {console.log("data",data)}
      {/* {makeTree(course)} */}
      {data.map((item,index)=>{
        {console.log("item",item.category_name)}
        return(<StyledTreeItem nodeId={item.id} label={item.category_name}>

        </StyledTreeItem>)
      })}
      <StyledTreeItem nodeId="1" label="Main">
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="2" label="Hello" />
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="3" label="Subtree with children">
          <StyledTreeItem nodeId="6" label="Hello" />
          <StyledTreeItem nodeId="7" label="Sub-subtree with children">
            <StyledTreeItem nodeId="9" label="Child 1" />
            <StyledTreeItem nodeId="10" label="Child 2" />
            <StyledTreeItem nodeId="11" label="Child 3" />
          </StyledTreeItem>
          <StyledTreeItem nodeId="8" label="Hello" />
        </StyledTreeItem>
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="4" label="World" />
        <StyledTreeItem nodeId="5" label="Something something" />
      </StyledTreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

Just return a